# I have PXE-M0F error after installing Linux Lite 6.2

Tags: system-installation, pxe

I deleted windows and installed Linux Lite 6.2
I'm stuck in the page saying that no bootable device -- insert boot device and press any key
Note: I can't find the secure boot option probably because my laptop is made before 2010

Comment: What is pxe-m0f? How can you "have it"? Bit confusing.

Comment: pre-boot execution environment
Idk how I could have it I just deleted the windows from two partitions then decided the free space to two partitions, one as ext4 / and the other EFI I

Comment: I mean, I don't understand what "having it" means?

Comment: Oh pardon
I mean I faced this error

Comment: Ahhh! Good news, not an error, just the firmware of your Mainboard letting you know it tries to not from network. Check whether you can manually select your hard drive/SSD to boot from. (At least that's what I'd assume, you're not really telling us *when* you see that)

Comment: Well I think I already boot from HDD not from network but it shows PXE-M0F: existing Intel PXE ROM.   No bootable device -- insert boot disk and press any key

Comment: That's why I asked to select the hard drive manually!

Comment: Well I just did! Actually many times before. Isn't that the option when we press F12 ?

Comment: Yep, that's what I meant. Sometimes the EFI of a computer needs to be told to look for new bootloaders, and manual selection of the device to boot from does that. Hm. Is the UEFI boot method turned off in the Firmware Setup interface of your Mainboard, maybe?

Comment: Yes exactly it disappeared! I mean the UEFI option. What can I do?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.